# Show$\:\frac{1}{\left|x^2+x+1\right|}\:\ge \:\frac{1}{x^2-\left|x\right|-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This is the answer I can come up with. I get the complete opposite of what I'm supposed to get. My mistake is probably in the first part, could anyone help me out?

$$\left|x^2+x+1\right|\:\ge \left|x^2+x\right|-\left|1\right|\ge \left|x^2\right|-\left|x\right|-\left|1\right|\:=\:x^2\:-\left|x\right|-1
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{\left|x^2+x+1\right|}\:=\:\:\:\frac{x^2\:-\left|x\right|-1}{\left|x^2+x+1\right|\left(x^2\:-\left|x\right|-1\right)}\:\:\:\le \:\frac{\left|x^2+x+1\right|}{\left|x^2+x+1\right|\left(x^2\:-\left|x\right|-1\right)}\:=\:\frac{1}{x^2\:-\left|x\right|-1}
$$

Comment: That is because what you are trying to show is false. Try plugging in $x = 2$.

Comment: Well, it certainly is not true for $x=\dfrac{-1\pm i\sqrt3}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting aside the backwards-ness of the stated problem, you have another mistake in your work.

In your second line, it is not necessarily valid to use the inequality that you used. You basically have established in your first line that $A\leq B$. You then use this in the middle of your second line to write $$\frac{A}{C}\leq\frac{B}{C}$$
This is false if $C$ is negative.

If you need convincing, try plugging in $0$ for $x$ into the relation you establish on the second line. This makes the denominator $-1$, and you will see that the resulting inequality ($1\leq-1$) is false.

Answer (score 1):

The original inequality is false. If $x = 2$, then $x^2 + x + 1 = 7$ and $x^2 - |x| - 1 = 1$. So $\frac{1}{|x^2 + x + 1|} < \frac{1}{x^2 - |x| - 1}$ when $x = 2$.

Comment: Thanks, seems the question itself is faulty? http://imgur.com/QzuMnta. Toon aan means demonstrate/prove/show. This course is already frustratingly hard without errors in the book. Thanks for the help!

Was my 'prove' correct though, assuming we'd turn around the 'larger or equal than' in the original question?

Comment: @Joey if $x^2 - |x| - 1 \neq 0$, then you were right. If you have that condition, then you can simply argue that  $|x^2 + x + 1| \ge x^2 - |x| - 1$ implies $\frac{1}{|x^2 + x + 1|} \le \frac{1}{x^2 - |x| - 1}$

Comment: @kobe See my answer. It's not correct if $x^2-|x|-1$ is negative either.

Comment: @alex that was a typo. It's supposed to read $x^2 - |x| - 1 > 0$.